# How a CUDA works

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have activated CUDA. Im having 24GB RAM for my system and 2GB NVIDIA Graphic card. Is CUDA a GPU rendering, that means it will render with 24+2 GB RAM or just 2GB NVIDIA Graphic card and CPU means it will run on 24GB only. I want to make clear how it works. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#gpu-rendering

Answer (score 0):

"If the GPU memory is full Blender will automatically try to use system memory. This has a performance impact, but will usually still result in a faster render than using CPU rendering."